# Reticencias em numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

O que significa o objeto `...` em um numpy array. Estou trabalhando com uma base de dados e quando utilizo o método unique em uma das colunas, entre os objetos que ele retorna esta `...` O que essas reticencias representam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele não "retorna" `...`. Quando o array tem um número de elementos maior que um certo limiar (o valor padrão é 1000) o numpy coloca `...` apenas para dizer que tem mais elementos que ele não está mostrando. Por exemplo

```py
a = np.arange(10000)
print(a)
```

vai exibir

```
array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999])
```

Esse array tem 10000 elementos e `...` não está no array.

Você pove ver o limiar com o comando

```py
np.get_printoptions()
```

que aqui mostra

```
{'edgeitems': 3,
 'threshold': 1000,
 'floatmode': 'maxprec',
 'precision': 4,
 'suppress': False,
 'linewidth': 140,
 'nanstr': 'nan',
 'infstr': 'inf',
 'sign': '-',
 'formatter': None,
 'legacy': False}
```

Você pode exibir todos os elementos em um loop ou mudar o limiar para algo maior. Por exemplo, se usar `np.set_printoptions(threshold=2000)` então arrays com até 2000 elementos serão exibitos sem `...`. Acho que 1000 é um valor bem sensato.